# Multiply increment_counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used `increment_counter` on a column in the `user` database with `reputation`:

```
5.times do 
  User.increment_counter(:reputation, @blog.user_id)
end
```

It increments by 1. I am searching for a way to multiply the increment counter.

Comment: Solution for what?

Comment: It still only increments by 1. It doesn't perform the loop 5 times. I would like to multiply the increment counter, as the title suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) method and do this:

```
5.times.collect do 
 User.increment_counter(:reputation, @blog.user_id)
end
```